# How to turn this into a straight line?

Tags: graphing-functions

Right now, I am trying to turn my graph (which looks like a exponential graph) into a straight line graph, which starts at the origin $(0,0)$. How would I do this?
My values are given in the attachment, and I have uploaded a picture of my graph (what the exponential graph looks like?).

- *[Values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jnL1V.jpg)*
- *[Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n18c4.jpg)*

Comment: Are you asking what line fits best or how to apply a transformation to make the graph look linear?

Comment: The graph is certainly not exponential, it looks (roughly) like a power function with exponent in $(0, 1)$.

Comment: You are correct TRavis, sorry. And user103828, I'm asking for how to apply a transformation to make the graph look linear

Comment: Try to fit a straight to the pairs $x_i$, ${y_i}^2$.

Comment: my x values are the velocities. so plot that to the y^2?

Comment: do you mean logarithmic graph?

Comment: The two pictures are exactly the same. Could you please give us the values you used to create the graph?